# How to Tether a Wireless Router to A Connected Computer

Tags: connection, wireless-networking, router

I am having some troubles with this.  Here is what i would like to do:

I have a desktop computer that uses a USB wireless card to connect to the internet.  I have an extra wireless router, and I would like to connect the router to that computer to create another wireless network to expand the range.  I have researched using my router (Belkin F5D8233-4v3) as a repeater, but the firmware is not supported.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to create a Network Bridge on your desktop machine.

1. Be sure to plug in your desktop to your extra router on the 'uplink' port, since your desktop becomes the source of the internet.
2. In the Network Connections control panel (Start > Run > ncpa.cpl), ctrl+click the Wireless Network Connection and Wired Network Connection and select "Bridge Connections"

This will make a 'dumb bridge' between the two network cards. Your router can be configured however you'd like, but to make sure you don't have network segmentation, try to set the router up as a *bridge* or *router* mode as opposed to *gateway* mode.